# Cual es el localhost de 000webhost

Tags: phpmyadmin, php7, mysqlconnector, server

Hola amigos lo que pasa es que tenia un proyecto en xampp y fncionaba perfecto , lo subi al servidor gratuito, pero se me perdio el css, asi lo tengo en xampp,

```
href="http://localhost/soporteencriptado/estilos/estilo.css">
```

en el servidor lo tengo en la raiz, ya coloque el nombre del la pagina/public_html/soporteencriptado
tambien intente con este https://files.000webhost.com/ pero no da

Comment: coloco el nombre del sitio web seguido de la ruta, pero no funciona

Comment: href="http://localhost/soporteencriptado/estilos/estilo.css"> solo que al localhost le coloco el nombre de mi http/:pagina.000wbhost.com

Comment: Cual es el nivel de directorio o carpeta donde esta tu archivo que quieres hacer referencia a ese CCS? así será mucho mas fácil ayudarte, porque dependerá de donde lo estas llamando  y no precisamente que tenga que estar en la raíz tu CSS.

Comment: No todo el programa está dentro de public_html lo que necesito saber es cual es el local host si el nombre de mi pagina o el file.000webhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

utiliza `../` en las url para moverte entre las carpetas desde donde llamas al archivo, este hace que retroceda una ruta antes, parecido al cd.. de linux/windows, por ejemplo, si lo esta llamando `index.php` desde tu carpeta `/public` ubicada en la carpeta raiz de tu host, y quieres llamar un archivo ubicado en `/soporteencriptado/estilos/estilo.css` también en la carpeta raiz del host utilizarias:

```
href="../soporteencriptado/estilos/estilo.css">
```

Comment: O sea que no tengo que poner el nombre del hoy, sino sólo../  ?

Comment: Para ser mas claro, en tu host esta la carpeta raiz "/", si tu en tu carpeta raiz tienes una carpeta llamada "soporteencriptado", y tu quieres acceder a ella desde un archivo php/html en otra carpeta dentro de tu mismo servidor, como por ejemplo, una carpeta llamada "public", en el "href" debes colocar href="../soporteencriptado/estilos/estilo.css", con ../ indicas que debe ir una carpeta antes de la carpeta actual donde estas, en este caso public, y luego entre a /soporteencriptado, en el caso de que el archivo llamase desde una carpeta dentro de otra en raíz usarias ../../soporteencriptado

Comment: Perfecto amigo me diste una gran pista, con lo que me explicaste, me puse una etiqueta "a"  y me puse a colocar rutas y no las encontraba y miraba en el navegador las pistas hasta que me funciono con esta <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../estilos/estilo.css">    Mil gracias amigo